# Facebook Like in Visualforce mail

Tags: facebook, email, salesforce, facebook-like, visualforce

i have created an  Visualforce email that wil be send to costumers.
In this email i would also like to have an Facebook like button as created on the following website.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Now i have created this and its looking good in the Visualforce Html example exacly how i want it,
but when i send a test mail the button does not show up.
so the rest of the html mail loads fine just not the facebook button as shown in the html example.

here is my code :

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FDatarecoverynederland%3Ffref%3Dts&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=400&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=80"  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:400px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

after reading some of the forums and salesforce developer docs i have also tryed `<apex:iframe`

Thank you,
M

Answer (score 0):

Most major email clients will strip out iframe tags from your email as a security precaution.  This article from campaignmonitor allows you to see which clients support it and which don't:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/

Your only other option would be to host the liking interaction on an outside site, then link to that in your email as a simple URL.